# What is an epoch, when using generators?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

What is an epoch when you're using a generator for your model.fit data?

it makes sense with the standard NumPy-array dataset - the epoch is the processing of the entire dataset.

However, with a generator, there's no length - hence no "epochs".

- Does the `epoch` simply represent an arbitrarily sized group of steps, when using a generator-dataset?
- Is there something special that happens at the end of an epoch?

Comment: If you write a generator, you need to implement `__len__` method such as `int( len(df) / batch_size )`. However, check this https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#what-do-sample-batch-and-epoch-mean and https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/ (Sequence  part)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an epoch is an arbitrary group of steps but generally it's one pass through the whole dataset.

However, you don't define that in the generator. You write a generator that yields batches, and then calculate `steps_per_epoch = int(training_samples / batch_size )` something like that, and then pass the `steps_per_epoch` to the training/fit generator function (In keras for example).

Regarding the second question: Yes you can evaluate the model at the end of each epoch and log it to see the improvements, you can also save model checkpoints.

Comment: `Regarding the second question: Yes you can evaluate ...` I was asking if the library does something special, like update weights (which would mean the epoch size wasn't redundant for generators). if nothing special is done at the end of an epoch, then I can simply set `steps_per_epoch  = 1`

Comment: Well here is the source code. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1092 Check this line:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1092  If you simple pass steps_per_epoch = 1, it will perform one training step per epoch which isn't what we want.

Comment: Why is it "not what we want"? There must be something special happening after an epoch? I know after each step, weights are tuned, are they additionally tuned after an epoch?